# PHP - curl_exec works on localhost, but not online

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with curl_exec.

```
    $id = "zuck";
    $url = "http://graph.facebook.com/" . $id;

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    // curl_exec should return a json encoded string
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $content = json_decode($content);
```

Then I can get informations like $content->name, etc...
It works fine with localhost, but not online.

```
var_dump($content)
```

returns NULL instead of the json string.

PHP on my localhost is 5.5.3, and 5.3.24 on my hosting service provider.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does `var_dump(function_exists('curl_version'));` output?

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` say that curl is enabled?

Comment: Maybe curl is not installed on the remote server (the extension is missing)...

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to enable it first. In PHP.ini look for `;extension=php_curl.dll` and uncomment it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : I just got my answer from an Italian forum (even if I don't speak the language, google traduction helped me!). 
Anyway, my free we hosting does not support the facebook API graph.
Problem solved.

@Amal Murail : 
var_dump(function_exists('curl_version')); returns true.

@Barmar : 
phpinfo(); says that curl is enabled.

```
cURL support      enabled  
cURL Information  7.19.7
Age               3
Features
AsynchDNS         No
Debug             No
GSS-Negotiate     Yes
IDN               Yes
IPv6              Yes
Largefile         Yes
NTLM              Yes
SPNEGO            No
SSL               Yes
SSPI              No
krb4              No
libz              Yes
CharConv          No
Protocols         tftp, ftp, telnet, dict, ldap, ldaps, http, file, https, ftps, scp, sftp
Host              x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
SSL Version       NSS/3.13.6.0
ZLib Version      1.2.3
libSSH Version    libssh2/1.4.2
```

So I guess curl is active on my hosting service provider, but I still can't figure out why it's not working with my code.

Thanks for your answers!